# sails-mongo does not support TLL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails-mongo

```
attributes : {
   username   : { type: "string",required:true,unique:true },
   password   : { type : "string",required:true},
   email      : { type : "string",required:true,unique:true},
   expireAt   : { type:'date','defaultsTo':Date.now(),'expires':'4m' },
}
```

the data store good, but ignore the field `expireAt` because `expires`  is not one attribute native of [waterline](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes) and then the document not expire never, ¿ is possible get one behave like the [mongoose schema](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_date_SchemaDate-expires) ?

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

Answer (score 0):

For get the behave of expires i have to do this :

```
  attributes : {
    username   : { type: "string",required:true,unique:true },
    password   : { type : "string",required:true},
   email      : { type : "string",required:true,unique:true},
   expireAt   : { type : "date",'defaultsTo':new Date()}
  }
```

remove expires of the  schema

```
        User.native(function (err, collection) {
           if(err) return console.log(err,"err")
           collection.createIndex({  "expireAt" : 1}, {expireAfterSeconds: 30 },(error,data)=> error ? console.log(error,"error") : console.log(data,"data") );         
        User
            .create(info)
            .exec( (err,user) => err ? res.badRequest(err) : res.ok(user) )
    })
```

Access to native driver of mongodb and follow this [tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/)